# conditionalPanel and selectInput

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Here is my problem; I can't set up properly the **conditionalPanel** to work with the **selectInput**. What I need is to plot *apligua* when "AP LIGUA" is selected, and *lascruzadas* when "LAS CRUZADAS" is selected. But Shiny is ploting both graphs.

Help please...

**In the Server:**

```
vars <- data.frame(location = c("AP LIGUA",
                              "LAS CRUZADAS"),
                 lat = c(-32.45,
                         -32.183333),
                 lon = c(-71.216667,
                         -70.802222)
)

output$apligua <- renderPlotly({
 theme_set(theme_bw()) 
 ggplot(aes(x = datos2$horafecha, y = datos2$altura2), data = datos2) + 
   geom_line() +
   geom_point() +
   geom_smooth(method = "auto", colour='blue', span=0.2) +
   ylab("Altura (m) ") + 
   xlab("Meses")
})

output$lascruzadas <- renderPlotly({
 theme_set(theme_bw()) 
 ggplot(aes(x = datos$horafecha, y = datos$altura2), data = datos) + 
   geom_line() +
   geom_point() +
   geom_smooth(method = "auto", colour='blue', span=0.2) +
   ylab("Altura (m) ") + 
   xlab("Meses")
})
```

**In the UI**

```
selectInput(inputId = "myLocations", label = "Estación",
                                              choices = vars$location),

conditionalPanel("input.myLocations" == "LAS CRUZADAS",
                                plotlyOutput("lascruzadas", height = "100%")
                                ),

conditionalPanel("input.myLocations" == "AP LIGUA",
                                plotlyOutput("apligua", height ="100%")
                                )
```

***(ERROR EDITED)***

Comment: Did you try conditionalPanel('input.myLocations=="LAS CRUZADAS" ',... ?

Comment: It works only for the first plot 'AP LIGUA', but when i change the input in the app's interface to 'LAS CRUZADAS' it does not plot the other graph

Comment: Well you should provide a fully reproducible example. In your code above I can see `output$apligua <- renderPlotly` and `output$chalaco <- renderPlotly` but no `output$lascruzadas<- renderPlotly`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1Akou7WM7XFSWZOWFdvQS10Tkk?usp=sharing here is the entire code. Your right it was a mistake there, but no in the main code. Im gonna edit this here.

Answer (score 2):

Your conditions should be one character string of Javascript code. So, something like:

```
"input.myLocations == 'LAS CRUZADAS'"
```

Notice the single quotes.

Comment: It works only for the first plot 'AP LIGUA', but when i change the input in the app's interface to 'LAS CRUZADAS' it does not plot the other graph

Comment: I looked at your code. You have two inputs with the same ID ("myLocations"). Even if the inputs are on different tabs, this will still confuse R. The plots work when you give one of the inputs a different name.

Comment: Perfect. Now works fine ! I know this is not a place to say thanks... but thanks Tom, really !